# Can you create dblink for the same database you are connected?

Tags: oracle, dblink, database-link

I know this is kind of weird but I would just like to know how this was being setup.
There are two database and they are the same (one is mirror from the other).
The first db is named "reportsdw" and the other one is "reportsdwx". 
I tried to "select * from dual@reportsdw" on reportsdw db and it worked, but when I did this "select * from dual@reportsdwx" on reportsdwx it is not working.
Can anyone explain that?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, but you have to create the corresponding database links.

Comment: you mean i need to create reportsdwx dblink on reportsdwx database??

Comment: @user646578 - yes. Someone seems to have done that on the `reportsdw` database; you can't use that syntax automatically on a new database, the link has to have been created at some point. (I'm not sure why you'd want to...) If the `reportsdwx` database was cloned it may have a (possibly broken) link to the original instead. You can look in `user_db_links`, `all_db_links` or `dba_dba_links` to see what is already defined.